# Tinymce stop adding a class "mceItemTable" to my table

Tags: tinymce

When I check the content area within tinymce using firebug, I notice that TinyMce is adding a `class=mceItemTable` to each of my tables. This is annoying because in the theme stylesheet it has definition for this which sets all tables to have a dotted bored and looks horrible.

Is there any way to turn this off?

[Cool jsfiddle for tinymce](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab)

PS: Is there a correct name for a css definition/group like this?

```
.className {
background: blue;
color: red;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set whatever class you like using this configuration setting: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:visual_table_class